# openpyxl number incorrect precision

Tags: openpyxl

I have a question about reading cell values while in `data_only` is True and `keep_vba` is False

I have the following code:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, keep_vba=True, data_only=True)
sheet = wb["sheet_name"]
my_value = sheet["E22"].value
# My Value is 12659.539200000001
# but in the excel file it shows up as 12660.00
```

if I do `sheet["E22"].data_type` I get `n`
if I do `sheet["E22"].number_format` I get `#,##0`

Is there a way to get the true value of the cell ?

I'm using `openpyxl==3.1.2`

Thanks !

Comment: With Openpyxl, I think if you want to enter the number 12659.539200000001 to a cell then later retrieve exactly that number; you should write it as a string. When later reading the cell value (which will be returned as a string) from Excel cast it back to float in python.